# In a table, select tr#myId and the nextone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I put together in the selector to select a tr by id and the next one?

So far:

```
var item = $('tr#CP') /*  Selects the item */

var nextitem = $('tr#CP').next('tr')  /* selects next*/
```

but how can I select both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#CP").next('tr').addBack();
```

The `tr#` is not necessary because there can be only one `#CP` anyway.  [`.addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) "adds back" the original selector to the collection.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't ever heard of addback, thanks for the info :)

Comment: `.addBack()` used to be known as `.andSelf()`; the new name is a bit more clear.

Comment: Very interesting! this question is not as stupid as I thought!

Comment: hey guys, check my own answer

Answer (score 0):

how come we didn't think of this one?

```
var bothitem = $('tr#CP,tr#CP + tr');
```

Interesting..